# gives unicodedecoderror when trying to open file

Tags: python, file

```
f = open('C://Users//fireqwert7//Documents//tesis.docx')


sts=''

for line in f:
    sts += line

print(sts)

f.close()
```

gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\regularexpressions.py", line 11, in <module>
    for line in f:
  File "C:\Python32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 66: character maps to <undefined>
```

If you can I would appreciate it if you could tell me why it happened and how to avoid it next time. i hate using things that I don't understand.

Comment: This will almost certainly not give you any usable output.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You're reading a docx-file (which is zipped xml) as if it were some encoded text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that somewhere in the file that you're opening (position 66, in fact), there is a unicode code that doesn't actually map to a real character. So basically, somewhere in the machine code of your file, some bits got messed up and now the byte they were part of no longer represents a letter in unicode encoding.

EDIT: Upon further contemplation (and as Thomas points out), this is because the file that you're trying to open is a .docx, which aren't encoded in unicode. They're encoded in a proprietary Microsoft format. I'm not sure if there's a way to open one in python and get readable characters.

If you want to work with the contents of this document in python, you'll need to either convert it (googling "docx to unicode converter" turns up some results) or copy and paste the text into a plain-text document.

Comment: docx is zipped xml. Trying to treat the content as (system dependent) encoded unicode is bound to fail...

Comment: Attempting to decode it as unicode and seeing whether it works (like python is doing) is a good way. If you want to automate checking, you could put it in a try: block. If you want to know beforehand, a good rule of thumb is that plain-text files (.txt, .csv, etc) are generally unicode, whereas those associated with a certain program (like Microsoft office docs), or that for any reason need to contain data other than just the text they display, are generally not unicode.